# How do I check for each character to be a number or a character in PowerPoint VBA and change their fonts accordingly?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I need to look through all characters and check if they are numbers or text items. If they are of either kind, I need to change their font accordingly. I have managed to do this in excel vba using some built in functions. But seems rather impossible in powerpoint.

Its rather primitive but does work. However, oddly, some parts get done properly others don't. I am unable to figure it out.

I have used this code:

```
Sub FontChange()

Dim sld As Slide
Dim shp As Shape
Dim foundText As Variant
Dim findNumber As Variant
Dim findCharacter As Variant
Dim x As Long
Dim y As Long
'Dim i As Integer
'Dim j As Character

findNumber = Array("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9")
findCharacter = Array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z")
For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each shp In sld.Shapes
    If shp.HasTextFrame Then  ' Not all shapes do
        If shp.TextFrame.HasText Then  ' the shape may contain no text
            For x = LBound(findNumber) To UBound(findNumber)
              Set foundText = shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Find(FindWhat:=findNumber(x))
                 Do While Not (foundText Is Nothing)
                     With foundText
                      .Font.Size = 18
                      .Font.Name = "Meta-Normal"
                      '.Bold = False
                      '.Color.RGB = RGB(255, 127, 255)
                     Set foundText = _
                        shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Find(FindWhat:="findNumber(x)", _
                        After:=.Start + .Length - 1)
                    End With
                 Loop
              Next x
        End If
    End If
    Next shp
Next sld
For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each shp In sld.Shapes
    If shp.HasTextFrame Then  ' Not all shapes do
        If shp.TextFrame.HasText Then  ' the shape may contain no text
            For y = LBound(findCharacter) To UBound(findCharacter)
              Set foundText = shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Find(FindWhat:=findCharacter(y))
                 Do While Not (foundText Is Nothing)
                     With foundText
                      .Font.Size = 18
                      .Font.Name = "Neo Sans Pro Light"
                      '.Bold = False
                      '.Color.RGB = RGB(255, 127, 255)
                     Set foundText = _
                        shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Find(FindWhat:="findCharacter(y)", _
                        After:=.Start + .Length - 1)
                    End With
                 Loop
              Next y
        End If
    End If
    Next shp
Next sld
End Sub
```

Comment: Of course, I did try without having to loop through the slides multiple times for numbers and characters. But this was while I was trying to figure out why it doesn't work correctly.

Comment: Check their Ascii code with `Asc()` or `AscW()` and use `Select Case` with `Case m To n` etc. m & n are numbers. Single Pass.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a more elegant approach. Two private functions to individually check the text. You could combine for an OR statement, but I left as two separate items for simplicity.

```
Sub FontChange()

Dim sld As Slide
Dim shp As Shape
Dim x As Long
Dim y As Long

For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each shp In sld.Shapes
    If shp.HasTextFrame Then  ' Not all shapes do
        If shp.TextFrame.HasText Then  ' the shape may contain no text

            If NumbersExist(shp.TextFrame.TextRange) Then
                'if Number exists
            End If

            If LettersExist(shp.TextFrame.TextRange) Then
                'What to do if text exists)

            End If

     Next shp             
Next sld
End Sub


Private Function LettersExist(yourText As String) As Boolean
Dim FindCharacter As Variant, i As Integer
FindCharacter = Array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z")

For i = 0 To 25
If InStr(1, yourText, FindCharacter(i), vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
    LettersExist = True
    Exit Function
End If

Next i

End Function

Private Function NumbersExist(yourText As String) As Boolean
Dim FindNumber As Variant, i As Integer

FindNumber = Array("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9")

For i = 0 To 9

If InStr(1, yourText, FindNumber(i), vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
    NumbersExist = True
    Exit Function
End If
Next i

End Function
```

Comment: This will not serve my purpose. Once I determine that a number or a text letter exists, I need to change its font. I doubt that can be done using your method.

Comment: The font for the specific character or the whole object text?